# How to enable Swig to emit C++ super class

Tags: python, c++, swig

I try to use overrides functions in Python, which are part of Cpp class.

```
class  A {

    public:
      int func() { return 0; };
      A();
};

class  B : A {
public:
  B();
  ~B();
};
```

I use the following command to generate the Swig python file

```
swig  -python -fvirtual -modern -keyword -w511 -module a_swig -outdir . -c++  -I. a_swig.i
```

But I see this python file being generated:

```
class A(object):
 thisown = _swig_property(lambda x: x.this.own(), lambda x, v: x.this.own(v), doc='The membership flag')
 __repr__ = _swig_repr

 def func(self):
    return _iris_swig.A_func(self)

 def __init__(self):
    this = _A_swig.new_A()
    try:
        self.this.append(this)
    except __builtin__.Exception:
        self.this = this
 __swig_destroy__ = _A_swig.delete_A
 __del__ = lambda self: None

A_swigregister = _A_swig.A_swigregister
A_swigregister(A)

class B(object):
  thisown = _swig_property(lambda x: x.this.own(), lambda x, v: x.this.own(v), doc='The membership flag')
__repr__ = _swig_repr

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    this = _A_swig.new_B(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        self.this.append(this)
    except __builtin__.Exception:
        self.this = this
  __swig_destroy__ = _iris_swig.delete_B
  __del__ = lambda self: None
packet_header_iris_swigregister = _iris_swig.packet_header_iris_swigregister
packet_header_iris_swigregister(packet_header_iris)
```

I want to see B being extended from A, so that I can use b.func() in python

```
class B (A):
...
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class B only privately inherits from A, so SWIG can't represent that in Python. Change it to public inheritance and you will see the relationship you're hoping for.